# Log4net and Unity register

Tags: log4net, unity-container

I'm trying to configure Unity to inject an ILog into my classes, where the type/name in LogManager.CreateLogger() is set as the class where ILog is being injected into.

Here is a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5950876/how-do-you-output-the-context-class-using-log4net-as-a-service), but for Structure Map

Answer (score 1):

I know this answer is very late, but I've recently had this issue.

There is now a NuGet package, [UnityLog4NetExtension](https://www.nuget.org/packages/UnityLog4NetExtension/), that registers the `log4net.ILog` interface and some Unity build strategies that allows you to just inject an `ILog` interface and have Unity create it using the class that it is being injected in to.

The code is also available via [GitHub](https://github.com/roblevine/UnityLog4NetExtension).

For example:

Add the extension to the unity container, before you need to inject ILog instancies. I've done this in the bootstrapper.

```cs
//add the extension to the unity container 
container.AddNewExtension<Log4NetExtension>();
```

Then, just inject the `ILog` interface and it will work

```cs
public class MyClass
{ 
    private readonly ILog _logger;

    public MyClass(ILog loggerForMyClass)
    {
        _logger = loggerForMyClass;
    }
}
```

This code works just as if I'd written `_logger = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(MyClass))`

Answer (score 0):

This it is must likely not the best way, but it's the only way I can find. So for now it's the best way :-)

```
Container.RegisterType<ILog>(new InjectionFactory(factory => new LoggerForInjection()));
```

-

```
public class LoggerForInjection : ILog
{
    private ILog _log;

    public bool IsDebugEnabled
    {
        get { return Log.IsDebugEnabled; }
    }

    public bool IsErrorEnabled
    {
        get { return Log.IsErrorEnabled; }
    }

    public bool IsFatalEnabled
    {
        get { return Log.IsFatalEnabled; }
    }

    public bool IsInfoEnabled
    {
        get { return Log.IsInfoEnabled; }
    }

    public bool IsWarnEnabled
    {
        get { return Log.IsWarnEnabled; }
    }

    public ILogger Logger
    {
        get { return _log.Logger; }
    }

    private ILog Log
    {
        get
        {
            if (_log == null)
            {
                // My tests shows, that is takes about 1 milli second to get the calling type
                var stackTrace = new StackTrace();
                string callingType = stackTrace.GetFrame(2).GetMethod().DeclaringType.FullName;

                _log = LogManager.GetLogger(callingType);
            }
            return _log;
        }
    }

    public void Debug(object message)
    {
        Log.Debug(message);
    }

    public void Debug(object message, Exception exception)
    {
        Log.Debug(message, exception);
    }

    public void DebugFormat(string format, params object[] args)
    {
        Log.DebugFormat(format, args);
    }

    public void DebugFormat(string format, object arg0)
    {
        Log.DebugFormat(format, arg0);
    }

    public void DebugFormat(string format, object arg0, object arg1)
    {
        Log.DebugFormat(format, arg0, arg1);
    }

    public void DebugFormat(string format, object arg0, object arg1, object arg2)
    {
        Log.DebugFormat(format, arg0, arg1, arg2);
    }

    public void DebugFormat(IFormatProvider provider, string format, params object[] args)
    {
        Log.DebugFormat(provider, format, args);
    }

    public void Error(object message)
    {
        Log.Error(message);
    }

    public void Error(object message, Exception exception)
    {
        Log.Error(message, exception);
    }

    public void ErrorFormat(string format, params object[] args)
    {
        Log.ErrorFormat(format, args);
    }

    public void ErrorFormat(string format, object arg0)
    {
        Log.ErrorFormat(format, arg0);
    }

    public void ErrorFormat(string format, object arg0, object arg1)
    {
        Log.ErrorFormat(format, arg0, arg1);
    }

    public void ErrorFormat(string format, object arg0, object arg1, object arg2)
    {
        Log.ErrorFormat(format, arg0, arg1, arg2);
    }

    public void ErrorFormat(IFormatProvider provider, string format, params object[] args)
    {
        Log.ErrorFormat(provider, format, args);
    }

    public void Fatal(object message)
    {
        Log.Fatal(message);
    }

    public void Fatal(object message, Exception exception)
    {
        Log.Fatal(message, exception);
    }

    public void FatalFormat(string format, params object[] args)
    {
        Log.FatalFormat(format, args);
    }

    public void FatalFormat(string format, object arg0)
    {
        Log.FatalFormat(format, arg0);
    }

    public void FatalFormat(string format, object arg0, object arg1)
    {
        Log.FatalFormat(format, arg0, arg1);
    }

    public void FatalFormat(string format, object arg0, object arg1, object arg2)
    {
        Log.FatalFormat(format, arg0, arg1, arg2);
    }

    public void FatalFormat(IFormatProvider provider, string format, params object[] args)
    {
        Log.FatalFormat(provider, format, args);
    }

    public void Info(object message)
    {
        Log.Info(message);
    }

    public void Info(object message, Exception exception)
    {
        Log.Info(message, exception);
    }

    public void InfoFormat(string format, params object[] args)
    {
        Log.InfoFormat(format, args);
    }

    public void InfoFormat(string format, object arg0)
    {
        Log.InfoFormat(format, arg0);
    }

    public void InfoFormat(string format, object arg0, object arg1)
    {
        Log.InfoFormat(format, arg0, arg1);
    }

    public void InfoFormat(string format, object arg0, object arg1, object arg2)
    {
        Log.InfoFormat(format, arg0, arg1, arg2);
    }

    public void InfoFormat(IFormatProvider provider, string format, params object[] args)
    {
        Log.InfoFormat(provider, format, args);
    }

    public void Warn(object message)
    {
        Log.Warn(message);
    }

    public void Warn(object message, Exception exception)
    {
        Log.Warn(message, exception);
    }

    public void WarnFormat(string format, params object[] args)
    {
        Log.WarnFormat(format, args);
    }

    public void WarnFormat(string format, object arg0)
    {
        Log.WarnFormat(format, arg0);
    }

    public void WarnFormat(string format, object arg0, object arg1)
    {
        Log.WarnFormat(format, arg0, arg1);
    }

    public void WarnFormat(string format, object arg0, object arg1, object arg2)
    {
        Log.WarnFormat(format, arg0, arg1, arg2);
    }

    public void WarnFormat(IFormatProvider provider, string format, params object[] args)
    {
        Log.WarnFormat(provider, format, args);
    }
}
```